# IBKR contractdetails.contract variables not accessible

Tags: python, attributeerror, interactive-brokers

I am currently using the IBKR api to request details about a contract, I am specifically interested in the conid, which is an attribute of the object Contract according to the documentation ([IBKR Api Class Contract](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1Contract.html))

As a test, I implemented a simple request contract details to print out the whole detail of the contract

```
def contractDetails(self, reqId, ctx):
    super().contractDetails(reqId, ctx)
    print(ctx.contract)
```

The above segment of code printout the following:

> 432280833,SOS,STK,,0.0,,,SMART,NYSE,USD,SOS,SOS,False,,combo:

```
def contractDetails(self, reqId, ctx):
    super().contractDetails(reqId, ctx)
    print(ctx.contract.symbol)
```

The above code printout the symbol of the contract searched, as expected.

> SOS

```
def contractDetails(self, reqId, ctx):
    super().contractDetails(reqId, ctx)
    print(ctx.contract.conid)
```

But the above code return an attributeError:

> AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'conid'

From my understanding of the documentation, the attribute should exist, and based on the initial printout it has a value of 432280833.

My question is, as anyone tried to fetch this information and succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the source code to see what fields and methods there are.

```
class Contract(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conId = 0
        self.symbol = ""
.....
```

Note the spelling.

Comment: Thank you, it worked well; I see, I've tried a variety of combination, but Uppercase I and lowercase C would have done the trick.
That would help if they didn't capitalize the documentation
And thank you for the tips of going to see the declaration

Comment: What you really need is and IDE with auto-complete.  I never have to look up field names, especially if I know the first letter.